# Can one uniformly generate complex numbers of absolute value less than a given constant $R \neq 1$?

Tags: random-variable, random-generation, uniform-distribution, circular-statistics, complex-numbers

Can one uniformly generate complex numbers of absolute value less than a given constant R?

This would appear to be equivalent to picking points $(x,y)$ uniformly in a disk of radius R, where $x$ is the real component of the complex number, and $y$, its complex component.

This question appears to differ from numerous others that have been asked, in that $R$ is not assumed to equal 1 (that is, the unit disc).

(Note: I am a Mathematica user [MathematicaQuestions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29989/paul-b-slater), not an R [no pun, intended] user.)

Comment: You may always take $R=1$ by choosing the disk's radius to be your unit of measurement.  Regardless, fully general answers have been posted in the duplicate threads.

Answer (score 0):

The MathWorld entry [DiskPointPicking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) asserts (without an explicit proof) that to generate uniformly distributed  points ($x,y)$ in the unit disk, one should employ
\begin{equation}
x=\sqrt{r} \cos{\theta},\hspace{.2in} y=\sqrt{r} \sin{\theta}.
\end{equation}
where $r \in [0,1]$, and $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ are uniformly distributed
variables.

So for points ($x,y)$ in a disk of radius $R$, it appears then that
one should employ
\begin{equation}
x=\sqrt{\tilde r} \cos{\theta},\hspace{.2in} y=\sqrt{\tilde r} \sin{\theta}.
\end{equation}
where $\tilde r \in [0,R^2]$, and $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ are uniformly distributed
variables.

---

---

Upon further reflection/application, I'm somewhat confused here by my original answer (trying to apply the MathWorld argument).

Say,
the maximum absolute value
$R$ of the complex numbers $x+ I y$, I want to generate
is $\frac{1}{2}$. Now (assuming $x=y$, which seems permissible), we have the relation,
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}})^2+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}})^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}= \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}

So, it seems that I want to choose $\tilde{r}$--before taking its square root--from $[0,\frac{1}{8}]$, not $[0,R^2 =\frac{1}{4}]$.

???

Comment: The proof for the radius distribution is that $(\rho,\theta)$ has density$$\rho\mathbb I_{0<\rho<R}\mathbb I_{0<\theta<2\pi}/R^2\pi$$ when moving from Euclidean to polar coordinates. Hence $r=\rho^2$ has density$$\mathbb I_{0<r<R^2}/R^2$$

Comment: @Xi'an    Don't understand the double-bar notation.

Comment: $\mathbb I$ is an [indicator function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=indicator+function).